# How to dismiss font substitution dialog box using JSFL

Tags: jsfl

is there any way to dismiss font substitution dialog box using JSFL?
I am trying to open a *.fla file using JSFL and I am getting font substitution dialog box because one font is not there, I had to click 'Ok' or 'Cancel' button manually to run JSFL.
How do I select or dismiss that dialog box using JSFL?
Thanks.
-James

Answer (score 2):

I found an option to dismiss missing fonts globally for opened FLA files, you can tick / untick this one which is not an elegant solution, but should work fine for you.

I haven't found any references in the JSFL docs about setting this option from code, but maybe possible, I have to look on it :D!

I can't upload any images here, but I added a screenshot of my Preferences panel so you can see where to find it: http://bit.ly/hO5uWT

Hope it helps, happy new year :D
Rob

Comment: Hi again, I checked some JSFL references but unfortunately haven't found anything useful. Rob